# JDBC connectivity from Airpal

Tags: jdbc, presto

[Airpal](https://github.com/airbnb/airpal) currently uses presto client to connect to PrestoDB. However as I understand, it can also use JDBC for this connectivity. Is there any code available for this purpose? Even if it is for connecting to any other database it might be helpful for me. The model for presto client looks a lot different than other models like JDBC etc.

Comment: If it would exist, don't you think it would have been documented? You're essentially asking us to do your research for you. Also, you should be aware the creating wiki pages in GitHub project to ask a question ([like you did](https://github.com/airbnb/airpal/wiki/JDBC-connectivity-from-Airpal)) is not the right way, if anything, you should have created an issue in [their issue tracker](https://github.com/airbnb/airpal/issues).

Comment: wasn't sure whether it qualifies to be put  under the issue  tracker...

Comment: It would have been a better place than a wiki...

Comment: Quick search "airpal jdbc" brings this issue https://github.com/airbnb/airpal/issues/201, so you're not alone. https://github.com/airbnb/airpal shows last commit on 26 Aug 2016. Did you consider using a different tool instead? Like Superset (https://superset.incubator.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airpal is using presto client connectivity and also using these objects (mostly for schema and data like Column, QueryResults etc.) internally in its various modules.

One way for providing JDBC connectivity is to move its lowest layer of DB connectivity (executeWith invocations of com.airbnb.airpal.core.execution.QueryCliemt: there is 1 for data and about 6 for metadata) to JDBC query execution. The JDBC results (mostly data and schema) can then be converted to presto client api equivalent objects and rest of the logic in airpal would follow.

Another approach is to rewrite airpal with native JDBC support by moving over to JDBC objects for internal use and communication as well. It looks like a much bigger change.

I am planning to add support for dynamically choosing between presto client or JDBC connectivity. I will use the com.airbnb.airpal.presto.QueryRunner to hold either a presto client session or a JDBC connection accordingly.